# Readline method in Android TCP Server not reading the message sent from my Python Client

Tags: android, tcp, server, client, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to send a message named "ringdoor" from the python client to the android TCP server. However, the readline method in the Server code is not reading the message.

please note:
1) that I am using "sendall" to send the message from the python client 
2)I am using the bufferedReader class and readline method to read messages from the client.

3) The codes for the client and the server are below.

### **Server code in Java**

```
package com.example.mmz_10.test7;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Server.class));

        Thread ServerThread= new Thread(new MyServerThread());
        // starting the thread to do work in the background
        ServerThread.start();

       // Log.d("Server.java", "Starting server...");
    }



    // https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html
    public  class MyServerThread implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        InputStreamReader isr;
        BufferedReader br;
        String message;
        @Override
        public void run (){

            try
            {

                int port = 8080;
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                // Now the server just started and is listening to  port 4457
                System.out.println ("the server just started and is listening to  port 4457");
                //To make Server  run forever, we use "while(true)" loop as shown below

                while(true)
                {
                    //Reading the message from the client (raspberry pi 3)
                   //   Log.d("Server.java", "Listening on port " + port);
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println ("the server just accepted the connection from the client");
                    System.out.println ("preparing to read the message" );
                     isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()); // side note :InputStreamReader is equivalent to DataInputStream
                     br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                     message = br.readLine(); //  message received from the client
                    System.out.println ("preparing to print the message" );
                    if (message!=null){
                        System.out.println ("the messagee is not null");

                    }else {
                        System.out.println ("the message is null");
                    }

                   // System.out.println(br);


                    if (message.equals("ring")){
                        // starting an activity from the service
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RingCall.class); // The " Server.this" or in general "ClassName.this" is used  for nested classes when an  inner class need to  use the outer class
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } // end of if




                } // end of the "while(true)" loop
            } // end of the "try block"
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //finally
            //{
              //  try
                //{
                   // socket.close();
                //}
                //catch(Exception e){}
            //}

        }// end of the "run" method
    } // end of "MyServerThread" class

}
```

---

```
**Client in python** 


Import socket
import sys

try:
    s=socket.scoket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

except socket.error:

    print ('Failed to create socket')

    sysc.exit();

print ('Socket Created')

port=8080

remote_ip="192.168.0.100"


s.connect((remote_ip,port))

message="ring"


try:

  s.sendall(b'ringdoor')

except socket.error

  print ('send failed)

   sys.exit()


print ('message sent successfully to the server')
```

Comment: If the server tries to read a line then the client should send one. It looks as if there is no `\n` at the end of message. Closing the client socket could do the trick too.

Comment: I think the problem with the "sendall" method in python since  it sends an object to the client, not a string .then, the redline method in java tries to read that object.but, it cannot since redline line should read strings

Comment: What kind of object would that be? 'ringdoor' looks like a string. But what is b'ringdoor' ? You might explain!

Comment: it worked when i used \n because readline expects "end of line" sign..